# Get Twitter trends through twitter4j in Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am beginner in Android and want get Twitter trends, but getting a null value in trends.
I don't understand where I made a mistake.

```
List<Trends> list; Trends trends; private Twitter mTwitter;

public  List<Trends>getDailyTrends(Date date, boolean excludeHashTags){
    try{
        list = mTwitter.getDailyTrends(date, excludeHashTags);
        Log.d("ab to aaja<><><><><>", ""+list);
    }catch (TwitterException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;

}
```

Comment: You should provide also the code where you instantiate mTwitter in order to see if you are missing something

Comment: mTwitter is object of Twitter class in twitter4j

Comment: i know that, but the mTwitter is correctly instantiated? did you checked if it is null?

Comment: mTwitter= new TwitterApp(this, twitter_consumer_key,twitter_secret_key);

Comment: successfully i got mention list, timelines and all through this but the trends is left

Comment: what parameters are you passing into getDailyTrends ?

Comment: m passing the parameter getDailyTrends(date, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
   public  List<Trends>getDailyTrends(Date date, boolean excludeHashTags){
        List<Trends> auxList = new ArrayList<Trends>;
        try{
            auxList = mTwitter.getDailyTrends(date, excludeHashTags);
            Log.d("ab to aaja<><><><><>", ""+list);
        }catch (TwitterException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return auxList;
    }

this.list = getDailyTrends(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-07-14"), true);
```

Also check if `auxList` is not null